# Open popup window on calling action

Tags: alfresco

I just started working on alfresco v 3.4. I have created document library action from the tutorials provided on alfresco site. Anybody tell me how to open a popup box on hitting action with some data inside it. Please guys, I am in big trouble !!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First reply on your early question and accept an answer, then ask another or you won't be taken seriously

Comment: Actually, I am not able to add comment as the required js files are blocked by filter in my organization. Also, due to this I am not able to up vote for answer. Now, adding this comment from my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Alfresco Share you have to use client side javascript. You can use Alfresco's built in functions (Alfresco.module.SimpleDialog) or just include your javascript library of choice and implement it using that.

If you'll use Alfresco's implementation (YUI) thenLook at this file:

```
YOUR_INTALLATION/tomcat/webapps/share/components/documentlibrary/action.js
```

And search for:

```
Alfresco.module.SimpleDialog
```

And don't forget to include/import your own client side files in your webscript. For this look at:

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.0_Component_Standards